# Why is Gibbs free energy different for different processes?

Tags: thermodynamics

Under constant pressure and temperature ∆G=∆H-T∆S.
Let us take a system with initial state (1) and a final state (2).Now let us change the state of the system from 1 to 2:

- Case 1) Reversibly by adding heat Qrev.So now the entropy change
  ∆S=Qrev/T.Also the enthalpy change ∆H=Qrev.So the Gibbs free
  energy change is 0(plug in the variables).
- Case 2)  Irreversibly by adding heat Qirr.But since the state change in
  both the processes is same, entropy change ∆S is still Qrev/T
  (Since entropy change is a state function).
  Similarly, enthalpy change is also a state function so ∆H=Qrev
  again so the Gibbs free energy is again 0.

.Why is this happening? I feel that the Gibbs free energy in the
second case should be Qirr-Qrev.But I am not able to get that mathematically.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: The difference would apply to the surrounding, not to the system. Surrounding entropy would be higher for the irr. case.

Comment: Like entropy, Gibbs free energy of the system is a function of state, independent of the process.

Comment: Hey Chet miller I saw your other answers on Gibbs energy and they were really good .Could you explain to me a bit more about Gibbs energy and give me some resources?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are looking for.  In terms of processes in closed and open systems, see Denbigh.  The real value of Gibbs energy, in my judgment, is not in terms of processes, but in using it to quantify interphase multicomponent phase equilibrium and chemical equilibrium involving chemical reactions.  To understand this, you need to understand the thermodynamics is mixtures.  This is covered very nicely in Fundamentals of Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and Van Ness, starting in Chapter 10.

Comment: Gibbs free energy is zero at EQUILIBRIUM

Comment: @chemeng No, it is not zero at equilibrium, it has just minimum there.

Comment: @poutnik ok if we’re going to be this technical. I’ll explain it in clear English $$\Delta G=0$$ at equilibrium, G itself is at a minimum . Good thing I was here to say it, you’re all welcome

Comment: @Chemeng It was rather essential than  this technical. $\mathrm{d}G=0$ and $G=0$ is a big difference.

Comment: I believe they’re both called Gibbs though(seems like a flaw in thermo and there are allot of them) I mean look at inexact differentials and this is what they accept as the basis of their field

Comment: @Chemeng  The flaw is probably somewhere else. V and dV are both volumes as well, but nobody says it is the same. 1 kg of graphite is in equilibrium, so dG=0, yet it's G is enormous.  It is quite difference between $G=H-T \cdot S$ and $\mathrm{d}G=-S \cdot \mathrm{d}T + V \cdot \mathrm{d}p + \sum \mu_i \cdot \mathrm{d}n_i$. They manage inexact differentials right, there is just a practical issue with inexact differential symbol, you need to copy or insert the extra nonhandy unicode symbol.